# WP-FB-AutoConnect: Unable to login with administrator account

Tags: plugins

I just bought and installed the [WP-Facebook-AutoConnect](http://www.justin-klein.com/projects/wp-fb-autoconnect) plugin but I am unable to login.

Below is the debug log I got by email.

```
---LOG:---
Starting login process (Client: 178.156.161.15, Version: 2.0.4, Browser: Chrome 13.0.782.15 for Mac)
PREMIUM: Premium Addon Detected (#671, Version: 22)
WP: nonce check passed
WP: Found redirect URL (http://blog.i18n.ro/wp-admin/)
FB: Initiating Facebook connection via the new API...
FB: Connected to session (uid 685872843)
FB: Got user info (Sorin Ionuț Sbârnea)
FB: Email privilege granted, but only for an anonymous proxy address (apps+116692738389663.685872843.060155133d98d19b8fa5f9c49090e749@proxymail.facebook.com)
WP: Searching for user by meta...
FP: Searching for user by email hashes (8 candidates of 8 total users)...
   Checking Users #0-7
   WARNING: Could not register hashes with Facebook (connect_registerUsers generated an exception).  Hash lookup will cease here.
WP: No user found. Automatically registering (FB_685872843)
PREMIUM: Autoregistration is Disabled; redirecting to /.

---REQUEST:---
Array
(
   [redirectTo] => http://blog.i18n.ro/wp-admin/
   [rememberme] => 1
   [_wpnonce] => 3786067e30
   [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-login.php
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the *premium* plugin and I had to solve the following problems:

- remove the application from facebook, because initially I allowed access to the proxied email address. Verifiy that your facebook account is a verified account before adding the application, otherwise the application will default to proxied emails instead of real ones.
- checked the request real email address in plugin settings - be sure you press the right save button (there are several different ones on the page)
- retried to login and when the permission popup appears you have to press the small **change** hyperlink under the email address permission and allow the application to access you real email address.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's connect.registerUsers method is deprecated and doesn't work anymore.

Basically, the plugin is out of date.

Comment: this wasn't true, see my answer.

Comment: It is true, as I know for a fact that the connect.registerUsers method doesn't work anymore. I had to remove it from SFC for this exact reason.